# Cannot connect to Wireless Network in 12.04LTS

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

Spent all night trying every solution online, but still none of them worked. I am a novice to Ubuntu, so Please help! Any idea appreciated!

Result of `lspci -nn`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express DRAM Controller [8086:29b0] (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:29b2] (rev 02)
00:02.1 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:29b3] (rev 02)
00:03.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express MEI Controller [8086:29b4] (rev 02)
00:03.2 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express PT IDER Controller [8086:29b6] (rev 02)
00:03.3 Serial controller [0700]: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express Serial KT Controller [8086:29b7] (rev 02)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82566DM-2 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10bd] (rev 02)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:2937] (rev 02)
00:1a.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 [8086:2938] (rev 02)
00:1a.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 [8086:293c] (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller [8086:293e] (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 [8086:2940] (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:2934] (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:2935] (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 [8086:2936] (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 [8086:293a] (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge [8086:244e] (rev 92)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82801IO (ICH9DO) LPC Interface Controller [8086:2914] (rev 02)
00:1f.2 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801IR/IO/IH (ICH9R/DO/DH) 4 port SATA Controller [IDE mode] [8086:2920] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller [8086:2930] (rev 02)
00:1f.5 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) 2 port SATA     Controller [IDE mode] [8086:2926] (rev 02)
```

and `lshw` returns:

```
my-computer-1234
description: Computer
width: 64 bits
capabilities: vsyscall32
  *-core
   description: Motherboard
   physical id: 0
 *-memory
      description: System memory
      physical id: 0
      size: 1959MiB
 *-cpu
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E6550  @ 2.33GHz
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: 1
      bus info: cpu@0
      size: 2GHz
      capacity: 2GHz
      width: 64 bits
      capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority cpufreq
 *-pci
      description: Host bridge
      product: 82Q35 Express DRAM Controller
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 100
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
      version: 02
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      configuration: driver=agpgart-intel
      resources: irq:0
    *-display:0
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: 82Q35 Express Integrated Graphics Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 02
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
         configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
         resources: irq:43 memory:fea00000-fea7ffff ioport:ec90(size=8) memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:feb00000-febfffff
    *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
         description: Display controller
         product: 82Q35 Express Integrated Graphics Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
         version: 02
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: bus_master cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:fea80000-feafffff
    *-communication:0
         description: Communication controller
         product: 82Q35 Express MEI Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
         version: 02
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=mei latency=0
         resources: irq:42 memory:f0000000-f000000f
    *-ide:0
         description: IDE interface
         product: 82Q35 Express PT IDER Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 3.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:03.2
         version: 02
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: ide bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ata_generic latency=0
         resources: irq:18 ioport:fe80(size=8) ioport:fe90(size=4) ioport:fea0(size=8) ioport:feb0(size=4) ioport:fef0(size=16)
    *-communication:1
         description: Serial controller
         product: 82Q35 Express Serial KT Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 3.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:03.3
         version: 02
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: 16550 bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=serial latency=0
         resources: irq:17 ioport:ec98(size=8) memory:fe9da000-fe9dafff
    *-network
         description: Ethernet interface
         product: 82566DM-2 Gigabit Network Connection
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 19
         bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
         logical name: eth0
         version: 02
         serial: 00:1e:4f:e9:01:ed
         size: 100Mbit/s
         capacity: 1Gbit/s
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
         configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=1.5.1-k duplex=full firmware=1.4-0 ip=192.168.1.84 latency=0 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
         resources: irq:41 memory:fe9e0000-fe9fffff memory:fe9db000-fe9dbfff ioport:ecc0(size=32)
    *-usb:0
         description: USB controller
         product: 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1a
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
         version: 02
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:16 ioport:ff20(size=32)
    *-usb:1
         description: USB controller
         product: 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1a.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.1
         version: 02
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:17 ioport:ff00(size=32)
    *-usb:2
         description: USB controller
         product: 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1a.7
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.7
         version: 02
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:22 memory:fe9d9c00-fe9d9fff
    *-multimedia
         description: Audio device
         product: 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1b
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
         version: 02
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
         resources: irq:44 memory:fe9dc000-fe9dffff
    *-pci:0
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
         version: 02
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:40 ioport:1000(size=4096) memory:fe800000-fe8fffff ioport:f0100000(size=2097152)
    *-usb:3
         description: USB controller
         product: 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1d
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
         version: 02
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:23 ioport:ff80(size=32)
    *-usb:4
         description: USB controller
         product: 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1d.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.1
         version: 02
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:17 ioport:ff60(size=32)
    *-usb:5
         description: USB controller
         product: 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1d.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.2
         version: 02
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:18 ioport:ff40(size=32)
    *-usb:6
         description: USB controller
         product: 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1d.7
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.7
         version: 02
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:23 memory:ff980800-ff980bff
    *-pci:1
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 82801 PCI Bridge
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1e
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
         version: 92
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
    *-isa
         description: ISA bridge
         product: 82801IO (ICH9DO) LPC Interface Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
         version: 02
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
    *-ide:1
         description: IDE interface
         product: 82801IR/IO/IH (ICH9R/DO/DH) 4 port SATA Controller [IDE mode]
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
         version: 02
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: ide bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ata_piix latency=0
         resources: irq:18 ioport:fe00(size=8) ioport:fe10(size=4) ioport:fe20(size=8) ioport:fe30(size=4) ioport:fec0(size=16) ioport:eca0(size=16)
    *-serial
         description: SMBus
         product: 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
         version: 02
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
         resources: irq:18 memory:fe9d9b00-fe9d9bff ioport:ece0(size=32)
    *-ide:2
         description: IDE interface
         product: 82801I (ICH9 Family) 2 port SATA Controller [IDE mode]
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.5
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.5
         version: 02
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: ide bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ata_piix latency=0
         resources: irq:18 ioport:fe40(size=8) ioport:fe50(size=4) ioport:fe60(size=8) ioport:fe70(size=4) ioport:fed0(size=16) ioport:ecb0(size=16)
```

and `rfkill list all` returns nothing

and `iwconfig` returns:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Update:

result for `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 062a:0000 Creative Labs Optical mouse
```

I have a Netgear WNDA3100 usb adapter from before, but I have only used it with windows. So if this computer needs an usb adapter to connect to the wireless, can I still use it?

Last but not least, thank you all for your inputs! Sorry that I couldn't update my question soon enough because of my work but I will try my best to respond as soon as I can.

Comment: We see no wireless device at all here. Is it a USB device? Please edit your question to add: lsusb

Answer (score 0):

May be your ubuntu initially drivers is not working so,you need to update your drivers to work wifi in ubuntu. Initially you need to connect your pc/laptop with "cable" and it automatically detect your internet connection.

Open "Additional Driver" option , it will search the drivers that are required for your PC and Card to support.

After that a list of driver being show, here you can select the driver according to you manufacturing company and Broadcom STA wireless Driver work fine with all cards.

you can update the drivers then restart the pc, unplug the cable and now you can search your wifi and give password for connection.

You can find the package -

```
sudo lspci
sudo dpkg --get-selections
```

Comment: Do you see a Broadcom wireless card or any wireless card in his lspci?

Comment: yes, Broadcom is not there, it have Gigabit board but my means only try to "Additional Driver" option to update all Drivers. Ethernet is showing so he/she can try LAN at initial stage.

Comment: The only wireless drivers 'Additional Drivers' installs is Broadcom. It has nothing to update if nothing is shown.

Comment: Thank you Gaurav, I actually tried "Additional Driver" many times, but nothing shows up. It always says that no proprietary drivers are in use in this system.

And for the package to be found by using:
`sudo lspci`
`sudo dpkg --get-selections `
What package are we talking about here? Is it the driver package to update?

Comment: In which pc/laptop you are trying to ubuntu because lspci --nn is not showing any wifi driver or your system is supporting wireless.

Comment: This is a desktop I recently got. It is re-assembled from old computers. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: your desktop have build in wireless or you attached any wifi device to access internet through wifi !!

Comment: I have a Netgear WNDA3100 usb adapter from before, but I have only used it with windows. So if this computer needs an usb adapter to connect to the wireless, can I still use it?

Comment: Please follow this link to install the driver -  http://askubuntu.com/questions/263312/cofiguring-a-netgear-wnda3100-usb-adapter/424066#424066