# Installed drivers for my adapter but its not working

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, adapter

This works for manjaro as well i had a problem with the headers but i fixed it so anyone who wants to know.

this is not a duplicate of this [Cofiguring a Netgear WNDA3100 USB adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/263312/cofiguring-a-netgear-wnda3100-usb-adapter)
because i installed the drivers he hast he doesnt have an internet connection and is trying to get the files whereas i already have them

So i got `wine`, installed my driver, went to the drivers folder, put the stuff into documents, installed `ndiswrapper`, and selected the driver .inf file.

It said it was a valid driver and that the hardware was present, but the USB adapter is not on and when i go to my network manager (`wcid` network manager), it says no network things found.

I am currently connected to the Ethernet. Any help is appreciated.

**Network adapter**: WNDA3100v3 Netgear adapter N600 series

Output of `sudo modprobe ndiswrapper && dmesg | grep ndis`

```
[  119.289665] ndiswrapper: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[  119.290674] ndiswrapper version 1.59 loaded (smp=yes, preempt=no)
[  120.426432] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: ntoskrnl.exe:'ExEventObjectType'
[  120.426452] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: ntoskrnl.exe:'MmGetSystemRoutineAddress'
[  120.426456] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: ntoskrnl.exe:'IoWMIWriteEvent'
[  120.426461] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: ntoskrnl.exe:'RtlStringFromGUID'
[  120.426483] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: ntoskrnl.exe:'__chkstk'
[  120.426542] ndiswrapper (load_sys_files:200): couldn't prepare driver 'rt2870'
[  120.427014] ndiswrapper (load_wrap_driver:103): couldn't load driver rt2870; check system log for messages from 'loadndisdriver'
[  120.427071] usbcore: registered new interface driver ndiswrapper
```

Output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0bc2:ab26 Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0846:9014 NetGear, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 03f0:134a Hewlett-Packard Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 03f0:034a Hewlett-Packard Elite Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cofiguring a Netgear WNDA3100 USB adapter](http://askubuntu.com/questions/263312/cofiguring-a-netgear-wnda3100-usb-adapter)

Comment: eyoung in that post he didnt install them i did so its a totally different problem for me i think

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `sudo modprobe ndiswrapper && dmesg | grep ndis`

Comment: i added the results

Comment: Your `dmesg` suggests that you have the wrong driver. Please show us: `lsusb` I doubt this is a 2870 chipset device.

Comment: i put it up there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `0846:9014` device is supposed to work with the native driver mt7662u_sta. First, remove ndiswrapper:

```
sudo apt-get purge ndiswrapper-common
sudo apt-get purge ndiswrapper-utils-1.9
```

Now we'll build the new driver. With a temporary working internet connection and with the device unplugged:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210
cd Netgear-A6210
make
sudo make install
```

Plug in the device and let us have your report.

You have built the driver for your current kernel version only. When Update Manager installs a later kernel version, known as linux-image, recompile:

```
cd Netgear-A6210
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot.

Please retain the file and these instructions for that time.

Comment: i did all that i plugged it in and then nothing happened

Comment: Did the driver *mt77662u_sta* load? `lsmod` If not, load it: `sudo modprobe mt7662u_sta` Then show us: `dmesg | grep mt76`

Comment: when i load it it gives me an internal error and when i do dmesg | grep mt76 it does nothing

Comment: heres lsmod after i load it http://pastebin.com/3xtggnzy

Comment: What is the internal error? Can you pastebin it? What does this tell us? `rfkill list all`?

Comment: linx@LazersMLGPc:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: also i dont know what the internal error was it was too long to screen shot it and i couldnt select it

Comment: i just uninstalled ndiswrapper turns out didnt install the first time i didnt have to pay more attention sorry

Comment: Ok thank you thank you thank you ive been working on this for a long time and after i removed ndiswrapper i restarted my pc and it works now!

Comment: I'm glad it's working! Please see my edit above.

Comment: okay i will do that

Answer (score 1):

When you install something with ndiswrapper, make sure to use modprobe to activate it. first try
`sudo modprobe ndiswrapper`
and if that does not work, try to reinstall ndiswrapper, and then once you do that, reinstall the .ini file. also, usually, windows drivers install a 32-bit version, and a 64 bit version. make sure you are using the correct version.

Comment: I doubt that Windows XP driver files, which are required for ndiswrapper, exist for this device.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the basic troubleshooting steps here:

First, check if any devices are hard blocked with RF kill:

`rfkill list all`

Make sure the adapter is recognized:

`sudo lshw`

Bring up the adapter:

`sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`
`sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid (network_name) key (network_key)`
*of course replacing `network_name` and `network_key`...

Finally...

`sudo dhclient wlan0`

to get an IP and connect to your chosen network...

Have you tried those yet?

Comment: i did rfkill list all and it didnt give me anything and then i did sudo lshw and this came up               *-usb:2 UNCLAIMED
                   description: Generic USB device
                   product: WNDA3100v3
                   vendor: MediaTek Inc.
                   physical id: 6
                   bus info: usb@3:6
                   version: 1.00
                   serial: 000000000
                   capabilities: usb-2.01
                   configuration: maxpower=200mA speed=480Mbit/s

Comment: but when i did the thing after this happens linx@LazersMLGPc:~$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

Comment: `iwconfig key` implies that the encryption is WEP. Why do you believe that PizzaCat is using an outdated and insecure encryption?

Comment: Your device may or may not be called wlan0, that's just common. Mine is called wlp1s0.  

@chili555 well, PizzaCat did not mention which type of encryption is in use; anyhow, in the event you're using WPA (which I guess you probably are), use wpa_supplicant.  

This article explains connectivity with wpa: http://askubuntu.com/questions/138472/how-do-i-connect-to-a-wpa-wifi-network-using-the-command-line

Comment: hwo do i check the encryption im really new btw

Comment: `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` ... This will show all the networks around. I think WEP says "encryption on" and WPA says "IEEE WPA" or something of the like.

 Or grab your cell phone, drop down your notifications, and hold the WiFi logo... go to your network properties... and it will also tell you there

Comment: And I am pretty new, too. Well a few years new, haha! But always learning. I'm just starting to train for Sysadmin Certification so there is a lot I know, then a lot of holes where I don't even know things exist. Hard to find a solid route but the best we can do is just keep hacking away at our computers until they work well, then somebody might start paying us for it one day :)